# Apache commons command line execute method is returning exit code -1 when running in tomcat application and throwing ExecuteException

Tags: java, command-line, tomcat8, apache-commons

Using Aapche commons CommandLine library, i am trying to execute an openssl command in a web application running in tomcat in SLES OS. below is the code snippet -

```
     CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("/usr/bin/openssl")
                .addArgument("genrsa")
                .addArgument("-out")
                .addArgument("/root/testcert_tomcat.key")
                .addArgument("4096");
        logger.info("Command - "+ cmd.toString());

        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setProcessDestroyer(new ShutdownHookProcessDestroyer());
        executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(null, null, null));
        executor.setWatchdog(new ExecuteWatchdog(60000));
        executor.setExitValue(0);
        try {
            int exitValue = executor.execute(cmd);
            if(exitValue != 0 ){
               logger.info("Exit value  - "+ exitValue);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("Exception - "+ ex.getMessage());

            return false;
        }
```

command - openssl genrsa -out test.key 4096

same command works fine when running from a normal java code outside tomcat web application or directly from shell command line. If someone has any idea please suggest what could be the issue.

Exception caught - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Not so sure but i tried to check the tomcat user, it is running as root -

```
libv222:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps # ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep tomcat

tomcat   13700 27.7 12.3 3610620 498412 ?      Ssl  20:20   0:46 /usr/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5000,suspend=n -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/share/tomcat/conf/jaas.config -Djava.library.path=/lib/emc/powerpath/remote_tools/latest/ -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

root     16591  0.0  0.0   4244   728 pts/0    S+   17:34   0:00 tail -f /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
```

Comment: Can you include the exception you are getting in your question? You have probably a permission problem, since Tomcat does not usually run as `root` and the `/root` folder is not writable by other users.

Comment: Suggestion: You can log the full stack trace `ex` - not just the message. There is often useful information to be found in the full trace.

Comment: Updated the exception trace, only getting a exception in trace. Is it possible to run tomcat as root to verify this behavior ?

Comment: Instead of running it as `root` (which by all means is possible), write the private key to an accessible folder (`/tmp/testcert_tomcat.key` e.g.) or change the folders permission to allow write by the `tomcat` user.

Comment: It was running as a root and changing permissions while writing key actually helped in the earlier case, but when i changed the openssl command to - ``` openssl x509 -req -in /tmp/ppserver.csr -out /tmp/ppserver.crt -sha256 -CA /tmp/powerpath-CA.crt -CAkey /tmp/powerpath-CA.key -CAcreateserial -days 821``` triggered same error even i have folder permissions now. Executing this command using apache common exec create a empty ppserver.crt file and returns exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, i had to switch from Apache commons to creating a Process to make it work. Looks like we need to execute this command in a new process for successful execution.

Folks suggested in comments that directory should have read and write access wherever required which is definitely a must for command execution.

```
private static boolean executeOpenSslCmdProcess(String host) {

        StringBuffer command = new StringBuffer();
        command.append("openssl x509 -req -in /tmp/ppserver.csr -out /tmp/ppserver.crt -sha256 -CA /tmp/powerpath-CA.crt -CAkey /tmp/powerpath-CA.key -CAcreateserial -days 821");
        String[] cmd = {
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            command.toString()
        };
        try {

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, CHAR_SET));
            result = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

            exitCode = process.waitFor();
            logger.info("ExitCode : {} ", exitCode);
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("IOException - " + ex);
            return false;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.info("InterruptedException - " + ex);
        }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions in comments!